# Finding differences in values between two samples

Tags: mysql

The table EXPRESSION2 has data for two samples.

Table Format:

```
Number  ProbeID     SampleID  ExperimID  Value  Type
  1     27574       1         2          6.35   AFFE
  2     35574       1         2          3.25   AFFE
```

...etc

How do I find the top 100 largest differences in probe expression (value) between these two samples?

Comment: Differences between what values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(`Value`)-MIN(`Value`) AS `delta`
FROM `EXPRESSION2`
GROUP BY `ExperimID`
ORDER BY `delta` DESC
LIMIT 100;
```